# VI make every first letter that comes after a underscore uppercase

Tags: linux, vim, regex, vi, string-manipulation

Found this site:

- http://unix.t-a-y-l-o-r.com/VMswitch.html

And it works for the first character but my lines are line this

```
this_is_a_string
```

And I would like this

```
This_Is_A_String
```

Any thoughts?

VI Command would be nice but any other simple solution would work as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do `:%s/^./\U&/` then `:%s/_./\U&/g`

the first will uppercase the first letter of every line, the second will uppercase the first letter after each underscore in all lines.

Answer (score 3):

Combining the two search/replace Rob suggested:

```
:%s/^.\|_./\U&/gc
```

will search for either the first char in a line or the first char following an `_`.

Explanation:

- `\|` specifies 'or'
- `g` will change all occurrences in a line
- `c` will ask for confirmation